# Process.start not working on windows

Tags: python

I am running python version 2.7.2 on a linux & windows box. I am running a script which generates child processes using `multiprocessing.Process` and wait for it do the desire task & then exit eventually. This works fine on Linux but on windows it is giving and error while doing `process.start`.
The following is the sample code snippet :

```
pobj = Process(target = foo, args=(bar,))
pobj.start()
```

Error on Windows System :

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I did some basic debugging and found the error is coming from "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py" file line no 255.

Answer (score 3):

Since Windows doesn't have a `fork()` system call, the `multiprocessing` module has to do some black magic to fork the process.  Basically, it tries to guess the entry point to your program, and skips all code executed before the fork is supposed to happen.

Probably you didn't include a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

guard in your code, which is necessary for the code to work on Windows -- see [the platform-specific documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Sven, In my case This snippet lies in a different Module and is getting called from Main script which has  "if __name__ == '__main__': " in it.